# Trig and algebra problem: Finding sides of a triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle such that $\angle ACB = \pi/6$ and let $a,b,c$ denote the lengths of the sides opposite to $A,B,C$, respectively. What are the value(s) of x for which $a = x^2 + x + 1, b = x^2-1$ and $c = 2x+1$?

I used law of cosines, then saw that I should apply the identity $a^2 + b^2 = (1/2)[(a+b)^2 + (a-b)^2]$, but I didn't know how to handle the remaining terms. (In other words, I got stuck early in the problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Applying [Law of Cosines](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofCosines.html), $$\cos \frac\pi6=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$$

Now, $$b^2+a^2-c^2=(x^2-1)^2+(x^2+x+1)^2-(2x+1)^2$$
$$=(x^2-1)^2+(x^2-x)(x^2+3x+2)\text{ applying } (a^2-b^2)=(a+b)(a-b)\text{ for the last two terms}$$
$$=(x^2-1)^2+x(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)$$
$$=(x^2-1)\{x^2-1+x(x+2)\}=(x^2-1)(2x^2+x-1)$$

As $x^2-1\ne0$ (which would make $b=0$)

$$\frac{(x^2-1)(2x^2+x-1)}{2(x^2-1)(x^2+x+1)}=\frac{(2x^2+x-1)}{2(x^2+x+1)}=\cos \frac\pi6=\frac{\sqrt3}2$$

Can you complete it now?

Comment: I was able to get that, but I don't know what to do with it

Comment: @AlanH, form the quadratic equation in $x$

Comment: by expanding the whole thing on the RHS?

Comment: @AlanH, edited the answer. The only valid answer seems to be $\frac{\sqrt3+1}2$